# R tcltk, changing icon causes a dead window

Tags: r

Has anyone experienced this issue before? I created a little popup tklistbox and changed the default icon. However, after changing the icon the listbox sometimes pops up in a half-dead mode. See picture below (left one is the half-dead one, right one is the active one). I don't have this issue if I keep the default TK icon.

Thanks!

DD

[image]